# CompoundIndexes annotation not working in MongoDB and Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to create compoundIndex on document in Spring. I could create manually on Mongoshell. But in Spring it's not working. Here is my code.

```
Document(collection = "Cars")
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'brand':1,'model':1,'colour':1,'fuelTypes':1}", name = "cars_compound_indexes",unique = true)
})

public class Car {
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private List<FuelType> fuelTypes;
    private String colour;
}
```

And also how can I update document when duplicate is entered.

Comment: Don't you need `@Indexed` annotation above your index fields?

Comment: Hi ammy! Have you inserted a document via the Spring application since adding the annotation? I believe it will only take affect after at least one has been inserted? What do you mean about updating the document when a duplicate is entered?

Comment: @jcarter  Yes, I have inserted document via spring application after adding annotation.Say I have compound indexed on name and brand. If I add another document with same name and brand it's a duplicate right. It is taking duplicates through spring application. And when cheked it through getindexes() it didn't add this index.    And update part, I want to findAndUpdate(indexed) I want to update non indexed fields.